# Como encostar Header no topo de uma DIV?

Tags: html, css

Como faço para encostar o header na parte superior da div, sendo que a div quando estiver com scroll em auto, não ficar fixo o header quando descer o scroll? Pois quando coloco a position do header em center, ele fica posicionado certo, mas não encosta na parte superior da div: Segue o código.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

#titulo {
background-color: mediumorchid;
position: center;            
}
        
div {
top: inherit;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid;            
overflow: auto;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
}
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<header id="titulo"><h1>titulo</h1></header>
<span></span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiramente, não existe `position: center`, você pode ver todos os possiveis valores do position [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

O que está causando a margem entre o inicio da `div` e a tag `header` é o `h1`, que se encontra dentro da `header`.

Você pode consertar simplesmente sobreescrevendo seu valor padrão:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         #titulo {
             background-color: mediumorchid;           
         }
         #titulo > h1 {
             margin: 0; /* Aqui sobrescreve a margem padrão do h1 */
         }
         div {
             top: inherit;
             width: 300px;
             height: 300px;
             border: 1px solid;            
             overflow: auto;
             display: inline-block;
             margin-left: 5px;
             margin-top: 5px;
         } 
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <header id="titulo">
            <h1>titulo</h1>
         </header>
         <span></span>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Coloque sua `div` com `position: relative;` e o `header` com `position: absolute;`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #titulo {
                background-color: mediumorchid;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
            }

            div {
                position: relative;
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                border: 1px solid;            
                overflow: auto;
                display: inline-block;
                margin-left: 5px;
                margin-top: 5px;
            }
        } 
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <header id="titulo"><h1>titulo</h1></header>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Coloquei também `left: 0;` e `right: 0` para distribuir o `header` por toda a `div`.

> quando coloco a position do header em center, ele fica posicionado certo

`position` não terá efeito algum com valor `center`. [Veja esta documentação do HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) (em tradução livre):

## A propriedade `position`:

A propriedade `position` especifica o método usado para o posicionamento de um elemento.

São cinco valores diferentes para o `position`:

- `static`
- `relative`
- `fixed`
- `absolute`
- `sticky`

Answer (score 1):

O elemento `h*` (`h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5` e `h6`) possui margens-padrão para cima e para baixo, e a margem de cima é que está afastando o elemento to topo da div, não o `header`.

Em vez de eliminar todas as margens do elemento, eu sugeria retirar apenas a margem superior, deixando a margem inferior normal, que é uma propriedade útil para elementos `h*`, fazendo assim:

```
#titulo h1{
   margin-top: 0;
   text-align: center;
}
```

> Adicionei `text-align: center;` para centralizar o texto, caso queira.
>   Como já disseram, o valor `center` em `position` é inválido.

Veja o resultado:

```css
#titulo {
background-color: mediumorchid;
/* position: center; */
}
        
div {
top: inherit;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid;            
overflow: auto;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
}


#titulo h1{
   margin-top: 0;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <header id="titulo"><h1>titulo</h1></header>
   <span></span>
</div>
```